Amadeus pricing API do not return included.bags
I am using self services API to search a flight and confirm the price and the bags
Here is my search body for flight offer
{
  "currencyCode": "EUR",
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "originLocationCode": "CDG",
      "destinationLocationCode": "PMI",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2024-10-28"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "originLocationCode": "PMI",
      "destinationLocationCode": "CDG",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2024-11-27"
      }
    }
  ],
  "travelers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "travelerType": "ADULT"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
  ],
  "sources": [
    "GDS"
  ],
  "searchCriteria": {
    "maxFlightOffers": 2,
    "flightFilters": {
      "cabinRestrictions": [
        {
          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
          "originDestinationIds": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "additionalInformation": {
      "chargeableCheckedBags": true
    }
  }
}

and when I get a response, I simply took the first one to call princing api. I was expecting to see in the result this section

But I do not receive this section. does anyone know why ?
Here is the simple application I am using
package com.example.amadeus;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AmadeusApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ResponseException, IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(AmadeusApplication.class, args);

        Amadeus amadeus = Amadeus.builder("******************", "************").setHost("test.api.amadeus.com").build();


        FlightOfferSearch[] flightOffersSearches = amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.post(readFileFromResource());

        JsonArray jsonArray = flightOffersSearches[0].getResponse().getData().getAsJsonArray();

        String body = "{\"data\": {\"type\": \"flight-offers-pricing\", \"flightOffers\": [" + jsonArray.get(0).toString() + "]}}";

        FlightPrice flightPricing = amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.pricing.post(body,
                Params.with("include", "bags")
                        .and("forceClass", "false"));

        System.out.println(flightPricing.getResponse().getData());
    }

}

